# Subscript not in Range MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm needing to get fields names from a query and put them into a dynamic array. I believe I have found the proper code this, however I get a "Subscript not in Range" error.

Code so far:

```
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Dim fld As Field
Dim o As Integer
Dim fieldCount as Integer
fieldCount = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryctAverage").Fields.Count

Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryctAverage")
Dim n As Integer
n = fieldCount
ReDim colHeaders(0 To n - 1)

For o = 0 To n - 1
    colHeader(o) = qdf.Fields(o).Name
Next o
```

Line of error: `colHeader(o) = qdf.Fields(o).Name`

I'm fairly new to VBA so I appreciate the patience and time put in to helping out! Thanks in advance

Note: All answer I've found have applied to non-dynamic arrays.

**EDIT:**

I now get "Sub or Function not defined" after removing `Dim colHeader() as String`

Error Line: `colHeader(o) = qdf.Fields(o).Name`

Comment: Why are you getting `qdf` off `db`, but `fieldCount` off `CurrentDb`? Are they the same? I would be expecting to see `fieldCount = qdf.Fields.Count` under the `Set qdf` assignment. Also `n` is redundant, loop would be clearer with `For o = 0 To fieldCount - 1`

Comment: @MathieuGuindon db is defined previously in my code. This is just a snippet with `fieldCount` moved in so there wouldn't be confusion as to where I got `fieldCount` from

Comment: You're using `colHeader` within the loop, but `colHeaders` elsewhere to cause that specific error..... but definitely take into account the other comments.  No.... you define `colHeader()` but then `ReDim colHeaders`....

Comment: Exactly what is the VBE highlighting when you get that "sub or function not defined" error? Make sure you've also replaced `colHeader` with `colHeaders` everywhere else in that procedure....

Comment: You seem to have left out the most important part of my answer... *change it to `colHeaders(o)`*

Comment: got it changed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim colHeader() As String
ReDim colHeaders(0 To n - 1)
```

You've declared `colHeader`, but resized `colHeaders`. `Option Explicit` can't pick that up, because the `ReDim` statement is perfectly valid as a declaration, too.

But then, `colHeader` isn't dimensioned, so index `o` is necessarily out of bounds:

```
colHeader(o) = qdf.Fields(o).Name
```

Change it to

```
colHeaders(o) = qfd.Fields(o).Name
```

I'd remove the `Dim colHeader() As String` declaration, and add `Option Explicit` at the top of the module if it's missing.

Comment: `Dim colHeader() as String` is needed to get passed the "Constant expression required" error.

Comment: @Symon no, it's not. `ReDim` exists exactly for this. "Constant expression required" pops up when you try to use a variable in a `Dim` statement. `Dim` statements aren't executable. `ReDim` are

Comment: Ah. Gotcha. I thought I was required to `Dim` a variable before I was able to `ReDim`. Am now getting `Sub or Function not declared`. Will edit question.

Comment: @Symon likely a typo. Did you specify `Option Explicit` at the top of the module? This will require all variables to be explicitly declared before the code can be compiled. Also, you'll have to replace `colHeader` with `colHeaders` *everywhere in the procedure*, not just in the tiny snippet you've given us.

Comment: Went back through and changed `colHeader` with `colHeaders` and it all works great. Thank you so much for you time and answer! Marked as answer. You're awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to use a `For Each` block.
This code builds a single string of field names separated by an `|`.
`Split` is then used to turn the field string into an array of field names which is passed back to the calling procedure.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim colHeaders As Variant
    colHeaders = FieldNames("qryctAverage")

    Debug.Assert False 'Pause code so you can look at colHeaders.

End Sub

Public Function FieldNames(QueryName As String) As Variant

    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim fldNames As String

    Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(QueryName)

    For Each fld In qdf.Fields
        fldNames = fldNames & fld.Name & "|"
    Next fld
    fldNames = Left(fldNames, Len(fldNames) - 1)

    FieldNames = Split(fldNames, "|")

End Function
```

Comment: Given `Fields` is an object collection, this would be a preferred solution (`Dim fld As DAO.Field`) - especially if there are a lot of fields. Would be nice if `Split` allowed ignoring empty entries, wouldn't need to trim that last pipe!

Comment: Good point with the `DAO.Field`... last few minutes before home so not thinking.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work properly for my situation. I could be completely wrong. The snippet I provided is in order to grab the field names and put them in to an array that I'll be able to edit in order to add new columns and calculations between the current fields.

Absolutely appreciate the answer !